# How to insert data into specific row MySQL C#

Tags: c#, mysql, database

so I have a MySQL Database and I want to write an IP address to a specific and existing row.

For example, username "Johnny" logs in and the system will go to the row for username "Johnny" and write to column `ipaddress`.

Currently I only know how to create an entire new row using:

```
queryStr = "INSERT INTO webappdemo.userregistration(firstname,middlename,lastname,email,phonenumber,username,slowHashSalt)" +
           "VALUES(?firstname, ?middlename, ?lastname, ?email, ?phonenumber, ?uname, ?slowHashSalt)";
```

So the question is how to write to an existing row by filtering via username and writing to a specific column.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look this post:[insert into values with where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9166197/3060520)

Comment: Use update query with where clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope that you are familiar with SQL UPDATE queries. Which can be used for modifying an existing row in a table, So here you have to use UPDATE Statements; Let me add a sample as well, Your code looks like this:

```
string querySql = "UPDATE webappdemo.userregistration SET" +  
                  " ipaddress=@ip Where user_name=@user";
// Add necessary parameters and execute the query
// It will update that particular row
```

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for an UPDATE statement with a WHERE clause
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html