# SQL Server INSERT INTO with WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, insert

I'm trying to insert some mock payment info into a dev database with this query:

```
INSERT
    INTO
        Payments(Amount)
    VALUES(12.33)
WHERE
    Payments.CustomerID = '145300';
```

How can adjust this to execute? I also tried something like this:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT
        1
    FROM
        Payments
    WHERE
        Payments.CustomerID = '145300' 
) INSERT 
    INTO
        Payments(Amount)
    VALUES(12.33);
```

Comment: Are you looking for an ["UPSERT"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27545377/335858)?

Comment: Please follow this link. Use both if and else
[https://stackoverflow.com/a/11010548/5063562](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11010548/5063562)

Comment: I'm actually looking to add Payment info to a table that has a relationship with a Customer that exists. There are currently no payments. I was trying to add the amount, but I think I actually need to add several other properties like PaymentID, CreateDate, PaymentTypeID, etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [insert into values with where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9166157/insert-into-values-with-where-clause)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you are trying to do an update statement *(set amount = 12.33 for customer with ID = 145300)*

```
UPDATE Payments
SET Amount = 12.33
WHERE CustomerID = '145300'
```

Else if you are trying to insert a new row then you have to use

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Payments WHERE CustomerID = '145300')
    INSERT INTO Payments(CustomerID,Amount)
    VALUES('145300',12.33)
```

Or if you want to combine both command *(if customer exists do update else insert new row)*

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Payments WHERE CustomerID = '145300')
    INSERT INTO Payments(CustomerID,Amount)
    VALUES('145300',12.33)
ELSE
    UPDATE Payments
    SET Amount = 12.33
    WHERE CustomerID = '145300'
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like having the customerID already set. In that case you should use an update statement to update a row. Insert statements  will add a completely new row which can not contain a value.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to insert new rows with the given CustomerID

```
INSERT
    INTO
        Payments(Amount,CustomerID )
VALUES(12.33,'145300');
```

else if you already have payment for the customer you can do:

```
UPDATE
        Payments
SET Amount = 12.33
WHERE
    CustomerID = '145300';
```

Comment: Ah. Then I can run `select Amount from Payments where Payments.CustomerID = '145300';
` to check that it was successful?

Comment: @MattLarson Yes you can run that select to check the result

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to perform update;

```
update Payments set Amount  = 12.33 where Payments.CustomerID = '145300'
```

Answer (score 1):

Better solution and without risk of deadlocks:

```
UPDATE Payments
    SET Amount = 12.33
WHERE CustomerID = '145300'

INSERT INTO Payments(CustomerID,Amount)
    SELECT '145300',12.33
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT=0
```

Comment: I want to +1 this, but what if you later decide to only Update when the Amount is different.
Do that (and run this script twice) and it will **_not_** Update a second time and `@@RowCount` will equal Zero (0), causing the Insert to fire and possibly break a Unique Key.
It is best to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Payments as P WHERE P.CustomerID = @CustomerID)` as your Predicate.

Answer (score 1):

i do inserts into a table if the record doesn't exist this way. may not be entirely what is after but it may be helpful

```
insert into x (a,b)
select 1,2
where 0=(select count(*) from x where a = 1 and b = 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like I actually need to just do an insert into the Payments table that has the correct CustomerID, as there are currently no Payments with that CustomerID, so I cannot update it.

I ran `INSERT INTO Payments (CustomerID, Amount, PaymentTypeID) Values ('145300', 24.99, 8);` and then `SELECT * FROM Payments WHERE Payments.CustomerID = '145300';` to confirm and we're in business. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try to update as below if you want to modify existing row,

```
UPDATE Payments SET Amount = 12.33 WHERE CustomerID = '145300';
```