# Pyodbc SQL Insert query with where condition

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

**I am trying to insert Data into a table with where *(NOT IN )* clause to avoid duplicate data getting inserted**

```
nvalue = data.value
nature = data.type
sid = data.Id
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME1 (ID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE sid NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_NAME1 )", (sid, nature, nvalue)
connection.commit()
```

**ERROR**:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")
```

**Also tried replacing the "sid" in where clause with "?" :**

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME1 (ID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE ? NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM TABLE_NAME1)", (sid, nature, nvalue, sid)
```

Comment: I guess you misspelled the params you pass - `id` instead of `sid`

Comment: Id is the column name and the sid is the variable name which contains the data

Comment: yes, and in your query it's reverse - `WHERE sid`, and then the param is `id`...

Answer (score 0):

`ID` should be used, instead of `sid`, since it is referring to the column `ID` for each record in `TABLE_NAME1`. Meanwhile, `sid` is the value to be inserted after filtering by `WHERE` clause. There is no relationship in between.

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME1 (ID, FieldName, FieldValue) VALUES (?, ?, ?) WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM TABLE_NAME1 )", (id, nature, nvalue)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, But i have to check the  existing ID present in the table with the sid (Variable) to avoid duplicates

Comment: It gives the following error - pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Answer (score 0):

SQL server doesn't support insert into where clause, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102013/sql-server-insert-into-with-where-clause).

As suggested there, you could use

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Payments WHERE ID = ?)
INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME1(ID,FieldName,FieldValue)
VALUES(?,?,?)
```

using values:

```
(sid, sid, nature, nvalue)
```

this means:

```
cursor.execute("IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Payments WHERE ID = ?) INSERT INTO TABLE_NAME1(ID,FieldName,FieldValue) VALUES(?,?,?)", (sid, sid, nature, nvalue))
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Checked with the above suggestion - pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'. (156) (SQLExecDirectW); [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

Comment: Okay, I see the problem, I'll change my answer