# IF NOT EXISTS in SQL query has this error : Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF NOT EXISTS" at position 0)

Tags: mysql, sql

im using this sql query :

```
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Payments WHERE CustomerID = '145300')
    INSERT INTO Payments(CustomerID,Amount)
    VALUES('145300',12.33)
```

but i get this error:

```
Error
Static analysis:

1 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized statement type. (near "IF NOT EXISTS" at position 0)
SQL query: Documentation

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Payments WHERE CustomerID = '145300') INSERT INTO Payments(CustomerID,Amount) VALUES('145300',12.33)

MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO Payments(CustomerID,Amount)
    VALUES('145300',12.33)' at line 2
```

this SQL query which I am using is from the answer of the question in this link : [sql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102013/sql-server-insert-into-with-where-clause)

based an another answer, I even used END IF at the end of this statement but it didn't work yet.

how can solve this problem?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server please correct your tags.

Comment: IF .. THEN ...END IF

Comment: @serg i used then and end if yet didnt work: https://prnt.sc/161ahk7

Comment: @AD7six, I used based my database and table and its a sample one

Comment: Do you use it within a stored procedure?

Comment: i use it in my nodejs code

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Flow Control Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-statements.html) only in stored programs. Use INSERT IGNORE when inserting a row with an explicit PK value. Alternatively if `CustomerID` is not a PK by chance

```
 insert Payments(CustomerID,Amount)
 select * 
 from (
        values row ('145300',12.33) 
      ) t(CustomerID,Amount)
 where not exists (select 1 
                   from Payments p 
                   where p.CustomerID = t.CustomerID);
```