# Locks are not applying and duplicates are being inserted. Which lock to apply and how to avoid duplicate inserts?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Here I have `TResult` table that inserts `TestResult` data into table using a procedure call.

If a test already exists with the same `employeeid` and `collectedtime` etc. with below conditions, cancel the insert.

This is being done to help prevent duplicate records from getting into the `TResult` table.

I tried `NOLOCK` and `TABLOCKX` in the `IF` condition. Here when the table is locked from a job, and different users are calling this procedure with the same data, in some rare scenarios, then it is inserting duplicates.

I should avoid the duplicates as per below condition.

When we have different data from 2 different procedure calls, it is fine to insert. But when we have same data from 2 different procedure calls when the table is locked, it is inserting duplicates.

Here I have few more columns also in the actual scenario. So, it is not possible to add a composite key constraints here to avoid duplicates.

How to avoid duplicate inserts? Any idea?

How can I move this to `WHERE` clause? So that I can get rid of extra `IF` condition?

```
/*
--Table creation Script
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TResult]
(
    [TResultID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClientID] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [EmployeeId] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [PolicyId] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [TestSourceId] [int] NULL,
    [TestPanelId] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
    [TestStatusId] [int] NULL,
    [CollectedTime] [datetime] NULL,
    [CreateDateTime] [datetime] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_TResult] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TResultID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
*/

-- stored procedure

CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [temsweb].[TResult_Add]
    (@ClientId bigint,
     @EmployeeId numeric(18,0),
     @PolicyId numeric(18,0), 
     @TestSourceId bigint,
     @TestPanelId numeric(18,0),
     @TestStatusId bigint,
     @CollectedTime datetime = NULL,
     @retval bigint OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN    
    DECLARE @TResultId  BIGINT
 
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TResult --WITH (TABLOCKX)
               WHERE employeeid = @EmployeeId 
                 AND CollectedTime = @CollectedTime 
                 AND (PolicyId = @PolicyId)
                 AND TestPanelId = @TestPanelId
                 AND TestStatusId <> 12) -- refusal
    BEGIN
        IF @TestSourceId NOT IN (3,12) OR @TestStatusId <> 13
        BEGIN
            SET @retval = -1
            RETURN
        END
    END

    -- SET @retval = -1

    -- Insert TResult
    INSERT INTO TResult WITH (TABLOCKX) 
        (ClientId, EmployeeId, PolicyId, 
         TestSourceId, TestPanelId, TestStatusId,   
         CollectedTime, CreateDateTime) 
        SELECT 
            @ClientId, @EmployeeId, @PolicyId,
            @TestSourceId, @TestPanelId, @TestStatusId,
            @CollectedTime, GETDATE()           
    
    -- Return the OrderId of the newly created Order
    SELECT @TResultID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    IF (@TResultID > 0 ) 
        SET @retval = @TResultID
END
GO

-------------------- Window1 ---------------------------
--Testing and mimicing Mutiple Users
-- (Lock the Table for 1 minute)
-- Block ( Lock ) table :
BEGIN TRAN  
SELECT TOP (1) 1 FROM TResult WITH (TABLOCKX)
WAITFOR DELAY '00:01:00' 
ROLLBACK TRAN   
GO

 select * From TResult

-------------------- Window2 ---------------------------
-- 1st Proc Call 

DECLARE @return_value int, @retval bigint

EXEC    @return_value = [TResult_Add]
        @ClientId = 12605,
        @EmployeeId = 16805332,
        @PolicyId = 31963,
        @TestSourceId = 6,
        @TestPanelId = 356,
        @TestStatusId = 11,
        @CollectedTime = N'2023-10-10 13:40:00.000',
        @retval = @retval OUTPUT

SELECT  @retval as N'@retval'
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO 
  
-------------------- Window3 ---------------------------

-- 2nd Proc Call 

DECLARE @return_value int, @retval bigint

EXEC    @return_value = [TResult_Add]
        @ClientId = 12605,
        @EmployeeId = 16805332,
        @PolicyId = 31963,
        @TestSourceId = 6,
        @TestPanelId = 356,
        @TestStatusId = 11,
        @CollectedTime = N'2023-10-10 13:40:01.000',
        @retval = @retval OUTPUT

SELECT  @retval as N'@retval'
SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

Comment: `insert into TResult.. select @ClientId... getdate() where not exists (select 1 from TResult where ...)`

Comment: Can you use `INSERT INTO WHERE...`? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102013/sql-server-insert-into-with-where-clause

Comment: Alternatively, if you want to lock the table for the duration of the stored procedure, you'd have to wrap your initial select with tablockx in a transaction with the ultimate insert. Assuming you were to uncomment `--WITH (TABLOCKX)`, right now it's only holding that lock for the duration of that one select statement.

Comment: "So, it is not possible to add a composite key constraints here to avoid duplicates."  Why? What do you mean by "it is not possible". Why can't you create a candidate key?

Comment: @CetinBasoz There are at least 5 other Conditions in the WHERE Clause. I have simplified Query here. But We don't want to throw Error. If the same Combination is there, we need to return -1 and so that UI handles the message accordingly based on the Return value.

Comment: `LOCK`s are scoped to transactions. Are you using transactions?

Comment: If you're just trying to avoid sending an exception to the caller, have you considered `TRY/CATCH`? You can avoid all this checking and tablockxing and multiple statements. Just `BEGIN TRY / INSERT / END TRY` and then `BEGIN CATCH / RETURN -1 / END CATCH`.

Comment: @Xedni I tried what you recommended. It is working. Doing more parallel thread testing.  Hope there will be no issues.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for `TABLOCKX` and you should *definitely* avoid `NOLOCK`.

The correct hints are `SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK`, and you put this on the `EXISTS`, not on the `INSERT`.

You could use a transaction, but in this case it seems simpler to combine the `EXISTS` into a `INSERT...SELECT...WHERE NOT EXISTS...` and check `@@ROWCOUNT` afterwards.

Note that you only need to check `@@ROWCOUNT` if you put a `WHERE`, otherwise it will *always* be `1` as the `INSERT` will always happen.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE temsweb.TResult_Add
     @ClientId bigint,
     @EmployeeId numeric(18,0),
     @PolicyId numeric(18,0), 
     @TestSourceId bigint,
     @TestPanelId numeric(18,0),
     @TestStatusId bigint,
     @CollectedTime datetime = NULL,
     @retval bigint OUTPUT
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;  -- needs XACT_ABORT for correct rollback

IF @TestSourceId NOT IN (3,12) OR @TestStatusId <> 13
BEGIN
    SET @retval = -1;
    RETURN;
END;


INSERT INTO TResult (
  ClientId, EmployeeId, PolicyId, 
  TestSourceId, TestPanelId, TestStatusId,   
  CollectedTime, CreateDateTime) 
SELECT 
  @ClientId, @EmployeeId, @PolicyId,
  @TestSourceId, @TestPanelId, @TestStatusId,
  @CollectedTime, GETDATE()           
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
    FROM TResult tr WITH (SERIALIZABLE, UPDLOCK)
    WHERE tr.employeeid = @EmployeeId 
      AND tr.CollectedTime = @CollectedTime 
      AND tr.PolicyId = @PolicyId
      AND tr.TestPanelId = @TestPanelId
      AND tr.TestStatusId <> 12
  );

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    SET @retval = -1;
ELSE
    SET @retval = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

You should also place the correct index to prevent the `EXISTS` from locking up the whole table. You probably need something like:

```sql
TResult (employeeid, CollectedTime, PolicyId, TestPanelId) INCLUDE (TestStatusId)
```

The key columns can be any order, so you may want to look at what other queries might want. If any of the columns are unique/primary keys then the rest can be moved to the `INCLUDE`.

Comment: I did not use XACT_ABORT before. I will try this.